# How can I pass form input value to an Action (struts 1)

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts, struts-1

I'm new using struts.

I need to pass the form value to an action when I submit the form. I want to use **input tag** no html:text.

How to do it?

This is my code:

form in JSP:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="address.do" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"><br>
    City <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city"><br>
    Country: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country"><br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

struts-config.xml:

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="myFrom" type="com.form.MyForm"/>
</form-beans>

<global-forwards>
    <forward name="pagAddress" path="/address.do"/>
</global-forwards>

<action-mappings>
    <action path="/address"
            type="com.action.MainAction"
            name="myForm"            
            scope="request" 
            input="/addressInput.jsp" 
            validate="true">
        <forward name="success" path="/addressInput.jsp"/>
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

ActionForm:

```
public class MyForm extends ActionForm{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
private String name = "";
private String city = "";
private String country = "";

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Override
    public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.name = null;
        this.city = null;
        this.country = null;
        super.reset(mapping, request);
    }

}
```

Action:

```
public class MainAction extends Action {

   public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
        if(getErrors(request) == null ||getErrors(request).size() == 0)
            return mapping.findForward("success");
        else
            return mapping.getInputForward();

   }
}
```

Comment: Are you having some kind of error? Can you describe better what is your problem and why this solution does not work?

Comment: When I enter the values in the inputs, I need to pass these values to action and after, when I submit the page I need to keep the values entered in the appropriate fields.

Comment: you should write the code in the doPost menthod in action

Comment: @AmarAgrawal What `doPost` method are you referring to? Actions have an `execute` method.

Comment: More details are required; if the submission is happening, just get the form instance and the values will be there. I'd also consider most any basic Struts 1 tutorial which will cover what's necessary. Note that you'll give up some S1 functionality by using the plain HTML input tags, like filling on the values back on a validation error, etc.

Comment: When I submit the page I need to get the values, that are using in other page, and keep it into the fields. I use the input tags because I use Bootstrap for the style of the form, and it's not available in Struts 1 tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access form values in a Struts 1 action, you need to cast `ActionForm form` to the type of form that the page uses, in your case `MyForm`. Then you can access its getters like normal. For example:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    MyForm theForm = (MyForm) form;
    String name = theForm.getName();

    if (name == null || "".equals(name)) {
        // error case; name is required
        // do something
    }

    if(getErrors(request) == null ||getErrors(request).size() == 0)
        return mapping.findForward("success");
    else
        return mapping.getInputForward();

}
```

If the problem you're having is getting the values out of `MyForm` into the JSP page, and you truly cannot use taglibs*, then you *can* get the form like this:

```
<%
MyForm theForm = (MyForm) session.getAttribute("MyForm");
%>
```

Then insert it into the page like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="address.do" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" value="<%= theForm.getName() %>" class="form-control" name="name"><br>
    City <input type="text" value="<%= theForm.getCity() %>" class="form-control" name="city"><br>
    Country: <input type="text" value="<%= theForm.getCountry() %>" class="form-control" name="country"><br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**BUT** you probably *can* use taglibs and just don't know how to add css classes to them. In the taglibs, `styleClass` renders to `class` in the output html. Try this:

```
<html:form styleClass="form-horizontal" action="address.do" method="post">
    Name: <html:text styleClass="form-control" name="name" /><br>
    City <html:text styleClass="form-control" name="city" /><br>
    Country: <html:text styleClass="form-control" name="country" /><br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</html:form>
```

Comment: how do I do a post request using struts 1 without form data but rather a string that I want to send as url encoded?